# How to read in Strings from an inner node in XML with Annotations (Java)

Tags: java, xml, annotations

i have to write a Config-Reader in java with the annotations from the javax.xml.bind.annotation library. The problem is that i don't really know how to get to the inner nodes (mailConfig in my case). Here is the format of my XML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
 <config>
   <avoidanceList>
      <avoid> item1 </avoid>
      <avoid> item2 </avoid>
   </avoidanceList>

   <ignoreList>
      <ignore> item1 </ignore>
   </ignoreList>

   <mailConfig>
     <from> From </from>

     <toList>
        <to> To1 </to>
        <to> To2 </to>
     </toList>

   </mailConfig>
</config>
```

I can read in the avoidanceList and the ignoreList, but my code can't read in the whole mailConfig. I read somewhere that two classes would solve the problem but this was not the case. This is my Reader Code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "config")
public final class Cfg {
  private List<String> avoidanceList;
  private List<String> ignoreList;

  private MailConfig mailConfig;

  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "avoidanceList")
  @XmlElement(name = "avoid", required = false)
  public List<String> getAvoidanceList() { 
      return avoidanceList; 
  }

  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "ignoreList")
  @XmlElement(name = "ignore", required = false)
  public List<String> getIgnoreList() { 
      return ignoreList; 
  }

  @XmlElements({
      @XmlElement(name="from", type=String.class),
      @XmlElement(name="to", type=String.class)})
  public MailConfig getMailConfig() {
      return mailConfig;
  } 
}
```

And here the MailConfig class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "mailConfig")
public class MailConfig {

  private String from;
  private List<String> toList;

  public MailConfig(String from, List<String> toList) {
      this.from = from;
      this.toList = toList;
  }

  @XmlElement(name = "from", required = false)
  public String getFrom() {
      return from;
  }

  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "toList")
  @XmlElement(name = "to", required = false)
  public List<String> getToList() { 
      return toList; 
  }
}
```

This is the first time for me to work with XML files in java so i know the code is maybe completlly wrong. I haven't found a solution with annotations so if someone could help me this would be great :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, works for me:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "config")
public class Cfg {
    public Cfg() {
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "avoidanceList")
    @XmlElement(name = "avoid", required = false)
    private List<String> avoidanceList;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "ignoreList")
    @XmlElement(name = "ignore", required = false)
    private List<String> ignoreList;

    @XmlElement(name = "mailConfig")
    private MailConfig mailConfig;


    public List<String> getAvoidanceList() {
        return avoidanceList;
    }

    public List<String> getIgnoreList() {
        return ignoreList;
    }

    public MailConfig getMailConfig() {
        return mailConfig;
    }
}

public class MailConfig {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "toList")
    @XmlElement(name = "to")
    private List<String> toList;

    @XmlElement(name = "from", required = false)
    private String from;

    public MailConfig() {
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public List<String> getToList() {
        return toList;
    }
}
```